# Cannot get my service worker to initialize in react

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

1. I have changed unregister to register in the index.js file.
2. Without any changes to the service worker or the web manifest, I run a build, then host it with serve (serve -s build). However when i run an audit with chrome, it errors out. the errors are:

start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline

Does not use HTTPS

Does not register a service worker that controls page and start_url

Does not redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS

So how do i get the pwa to work out of the box? switching unregister to register does not seem to work.

service worker:

```
const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
  window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
  window.location.hostname.match(/^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/)
);

export function register(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/#/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log('This web app is being served cache-first by a service ');
        });
      } else {
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
      ) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "MEX Broadband",
    "short_name": "MEX Broadband",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "theme_color": "#ffffff",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "display": "standalone",
  "start_url": "./index.html"
}
```

Comment: You provided little info. How your manifest looks like? How your service worker looks like?

Comment: they are both stock from create react app. No changes.